# object x is not a member of struct y

Tags: c++

```
#pragma once
#include "Predefined.h"

#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

namespace Packets
{
enum { EnumLoginData, EnumPlayerData };

struct LoginData
{
    std::string username;
    std::string password;
};

struct PlayerData
{
    Predefined::Vector2 position;
};

struct MainPacket
{
    char type;
    int id;

    LoginData loginData;
    vector<PlayerData> playerData;
};
}
```

The code above is a single header file called PacketDefines.h. I have a couple of structs prepared as you can see which I will use in another part of my program. Now, the struct PlayerData uses a Predefined::Vector2 object which is a custom struct I created in Predefined.h which is included in the current header file.

The problem is that I get this error on it:

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'position'
```

Also, this makes it so that something else in the code, that depends on this struct causes to throw an error:

```
error C2039: 'position' : is not a member of 'Packets::PlayerData'
```

This is the Predefined header file:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include "PacketDefines.h"

// some other includes

using namespace std;

#define LOBBY_MAX_CONNECTIONS 5

#define MAX_DATA_SIZE 512

namespace Predefined
{
struct Vector2
{
    Vector2(float valueX = 0.0f, float valueY = 0.0f) : x(valueX), y(valueY) {}

    float x;
    float y;
};

struct Vector3
{
    Vector3(float valueX = 0.0f, float valueY = 0.0f, float valueZ = 0.0f) : x(valueX), y(valueY), z(valueZ) {}

    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

struct Connection
{
    int ID;
    SOCKET socket;
    Packets::PlayerData playerData;
};

struct Lobby
{
    string lobbyName;
    vector<Connection> connectionList;
};
}
```

I have no idea what is going on since everything is linked like it should as far as I know. I hope my problem is clear and someone can help me solving these errors.

Comment: They include each other. This is called a circular dependency. You have to remove this dependency some how.

Comment: I'll check it out. Thing is that they need each other and I want to keep them seperated as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a superficial overview, but your "Predefined.h" contains two distinct sections; the first are your `Vector` classes, the second are more complex classes which contain application logic. To overcome this, you actually need three header files:

- `Vectors.h` -> Should define `Vector2` and `Vector3`, and include *none* of your application structures
- `PacketDefines.h` -> Should `#include "Vectors.h"` and nothing else (doesn't need to include `Predefined.h`).
- `Connection.h` -> Should `#include "PacketDefines.h"`.

Out of scope for this question, I'd also recommend changing your header names to something more meaningful (yes, headers typically *declare* symbols and *define* structures; so what?).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. Yeah, I'll probably call the vector one CustomMath or something. I'll come up with better names eventually